# How do I restart Synergy in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, synergy

I have the free (aka old) version of [Synergy](https://symless.com/synergy) installed on macOS Sierra. For some reason all the options in the drop down menu are greyed out and it won't connect to the server. How do I restart Synergy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution:

1. Find the Synergy process in the Activity Monitor.
2. Hit the X to quit the process.
3. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and search for Synergy to start it again.

Answer (score 2):

For Synergy 2:

> Sometimes the background service can get into a bad state. This is most commonly caused by either sleep/resume, a change in IP address, or just random bad luck, but other factors can affect it as well. We're urgently working on a fix for this problem.
>
> In the meantime, please could you open the Synergy config app and press the key combination Shift+F5 on both computers. This will restart the service, and you'll have to click Retry afterward. You may need to repeat the key combination it a few times, but if that doesn't work, you can also try restarting your computers. This should solve the problem, but if not, please send me your most recent log links so we can try some more solutions.
>
> If that doesn't work, please contact support.

https://symless.com/synergy/help/connection/background-service

Edit:

After viewing the Synergy processes in the activity monitor as [Philip suggested](https://superuser.com/q/1231825/573254), I found multiple synergy-core processes. Terminating them all solved my problem!